# How to get the data that you wear the Apple watch on your left-hand or right-hand

Tags: watchkit, watchos-3

I want to get the data that you wear the Apple watch on your left-hand or right-hand.
In addition, I hope to know the way to get the data that your Digital Crown is on the right or left of the Apple watch.

However, I cannot find the way to do it.
Please teach me how to if you know the way.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().wristLocation
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1650810-wristlocation

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().crownOrientation
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/1650805-crownorientation